# QNXStageWebView on top of all containers

Tags: webview, blackberry-playbook

I am developing an application for blackberry playbook using flex hero and html contents are displayed using QNXStageWebView.But the problem is when i add this webview to stage its coming on  top of all other display objects.I am not able to control it.I need to solve it then only i can continue my work. can anyone help me to solve this issue???

```
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import qnx.media.QNXStageWebView;

        public var webview:QNXStageWebView  =   new QNXStageWebView();

        protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var rect:Rectangle  =   new Rectangle(0,0,200,400);
            webview.stage           =   stage;
            webview.viewPort        =   rect;
            webview.zOrder          =   1;

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button id="buttn" x="0" y="0"/>
```

when i run this code am not able to see that button. i need to display it on top of webview.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the [zOrder](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/airapi/1.0.0/qnx/media/QNXStageWebView.html#zOrder)? It's like the z-order-property of html to arrange children in certain layers.

Comment: I have tried Zorder property. But that also not working....i need to control depth between QNXStageWebView  and flex hero spark display components.Is it possible??

Comment: Try the official PlayBook Adobe AIR SDK Dev-forum: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/instead-of-QNXStageWebView/m-p/1053113/message-uid/1053113#U1053113

Comment: how u make stage transparent? i have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, currently it just can't do that, all QNXStageWebView always placed on top of other object, we better wait for adobe / RIM to improve the implementation.